# How to calculate the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate the integral
$$
\int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {t^2}} }}{e^{ - itx}}dt} 
$$
It seems like that Residue Theorem can't be used here. Is anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: [It seems like it is known, but not in terms of elementary functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+Transform+1%2F(sqrt(1%2Bx%5E2)))...

Answer (score 3):

If you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), you will see that
$$2 K_0(x)=\int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{e^{ixt}}{{\sqrt {1 + {t^2}} }}dt}$$ and then the result already given by mrtaurho

Comment: Do you know how to judge whether it belongs to the first kind or the second kind if we can show that it fits into the Modified Bessel equation. (Pretend that we don't know the second kind has such form.)

Comment: @YanjieZhong Probably has to do with boundedness at $x\to\pm\infty$

Comment: @Dylan oh yes, maybe we just need to verify values at some points